# Объединение двух больших файлов по ID

Tags: c#, sql, csv

У меня есть 2 больших файла, весом более 1 ГБ, один формата SQL другой CSV.

1. Формат строки первого файла: `id, int, DateTime, 1, 1`.
2. Формат строки второго файла: `id, string, string, DateTime`

Как можно объединить эти файлы в 1 по id: `id, int, DateTime, 1, 1, string, string, DateTime`?

Пытался читать первый файл буфером и сравнивать id со вторым, так же читая с буфером, но это очень долго, ибо id идут не по порядку, у первой строки может быть id 2, а у второй 1241254

Comment: Импортировать в любую (ну кроме MS ACCess, конечно) СУБД, имеющуюся под рукой, там и объединить.

Comment: Но если принципиально руками, то внешняя сортировка слиянием содержимого файлов по id с последующим объединением в один проход. В плане реализации задачка получается интересная, в плане времени - я бы тоже в БД загрузил и не мучался.

Comment: Еще один "странный" вариант - первым проходом по обоим файлам вычитать последовательно Id в какой-нибудь словарь, где ключом будет Id, а значением позиция строки в обоих файлах. Затем берем значения из словаря и читаем строки с указанных позиций. Это попроще и побыстрее сортировки будет, но памяти сожрет много на словарь, да и у рандомного доступа к файлу такая себе производительность.